# Start NodeJs when starting Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

I have a Rails-App which includes a nodejs server. Is it possible to start and stop the nodejs server when I start/stop the rails server?

I want to put `rails s` in my terminal and both server should start. By pressing ctrl + c both server should stop.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a good candidate for a Rake task, something like (not tested):

```
# Rakefile
desc "Start Node and Rails servers"
task :start_servers do
  `node myapp.js`
  `rails s`
end
```

(And you can specify options as at the command line, for example to run on different ports, etc.)

Use `rake start_servers` to run the task.

Comment: There is no console output

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution. Put this line in an initializer:

`system "node ./nodejs/nodejs-server.js &"`

Comment: I was thinking afterward that it should probably just be a shell script (in other words, external to both), or controlled by a third-party solution (as part of "devops" in a production-oriented environment).